# Don't Open file upload dialog box upon selecting a date from igdatepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ignite-ui

[image: igdatepicker dropdown open a file upload dialog]

how to prevent that click on a igdatepicker dropdown dont't trigger the file upload dialog popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the `mousedown` event on the calendar container and prevent its propagation down to other element rendered below the container.

```
$("#pickerID .ui-datepicker-calendar").on("mousedown", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```